# Split a file of text at delimiters and separate integers and text in c

Tags: c, io

I am reading text from an input file in. I have to separate text from scores ie

```
John Doe 100 95 67 85 
jane doe 67 78 99
```

and then average the numbers. I can separate by the spaces using strtok but how can i tell when i have an integer? i need to split the reading of names and of integers into 2 functions. My code to read it works but i need to stop at the end of each name. I attempted to use numbers converted to strings and using strcmp however it did not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void read_reverse_write(FILE * ptr_file, FILE * op);
void write_and_avarage(int * fp, char * op);
//int checker(char *token);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    FILE *fp;
    FILE *op;
    //opens quiz and checks and checks to make sure it did
    fp = fopen("quiz.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return (-1);
    }
    //opens op and checks that it did 
    op = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (op == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file");
        return (-1);
    }
    // runs read reverse write
    read_reverse_write(fp, op);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(op);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void read_reverse_write(FILE * ptr_file, FILE * op) {
    char buf[1000];
    char *token;
    const char delim[2] = " ";
    fgets(buf, 1000, ptr_file);
    token = strtok(buf, delim);

    while (token != 100) {
            fprintf(op, "%s ", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);


    }


}

/*void write_and_avarage(int * fp, char * op) {

}

int checker(char *token) {
    char *arr[102];
    char ph[4];
    for (int p = 0; p < 100; p++) {
        if (p < 10) {
            snprintf(ph, 1, "%d", p);
            arr[p] = ph;
        } else if (p < 99) {
            snprintf(ph, 2, "%d", p);
            arr[p] = ph;
        } else if (p = 100) {
            snprintf(ph, 3, "%d", p);
            arr[p] = ph;
        }
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
        if (strcmp(token, arr[z]) == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            z++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

*/
```

Comment: Check the C Standard library for conversion of character to int. hint *atoi*

Comment: tried that my compiler didnt reconize it as a valid function

Comment: If you look at the first character of each token (if not `NULL`) produced by `strtok` you can tell if it is `isalpha()` or `isdigit()` in the first case build the name, in the second, chalk up another score.

Comment: hmmmm.... what compiler are you using? you **did** try it out?

Comment: @WeatherVane that could work however what if my token is a length of 20 and only 12 are characters? How would i implement that

Comment: By assuming that my name has to be "Weather123 Vane987". My suggestion would also take care of a *three word name* such as "Luigi Da Silva".

Comment: Yes @t0mm13b i did im using netbeans ide not compiler and the function is itoa(num,Str,10) (10 because it is decimal) Is that correct?

Comment: Please note that `atoi` will not distinguish `0` from `W`.

Comment: that's integer to ascii.. you want the reverse if you want to be able to average the integers.

Comment: @WeatherVane isdigit() worked. Now i have to loop it through the file but it works for the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check the whether the string is a number or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_NUM 9
#define MIN_NUM 0
#define ZERO 0
#define MAX_SIZE 1024

int checkDigit(int num, int len)
{
    int divisor = 1, checkVal = 0;
    if(len <= 2)
        divisor = 10;
    else if(len > 2)
    {
        len = len - 1;
        while(len != ZERO)
        {
            divisor = divisor * 10;
            len = len - 1;
        }
    }
    checkVal = num/divisor;
    if(checkVal > MIN_NUM && checkVal <= MAX_NUM)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


void main()
{
    char array[MAX_SIZE] = "JOHN DOE 120 DOE HELLO 2323 90909";
    char *split_token = NULL;
    int status = 2, len = 0, sum = 0, total_digits = 0;
    float average = 0;
    split_token = strtok(array, " ");
    while( split_token != NULL )
    {
        len = strlen(split_token);
        status = checkDigit(atoi(split_token), len);
        if (1 == status)
        {
            sum = sum + atoi(split_token);
            total_digits = total_digits + 1;
        }
        split_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    average = (float)sum/total_digits;
    printf("Average is : %f\n", average);
}
```

This code will check whether your string is a number or not and finally calculate the average of all the numbers in the given string.
If you need to read from a file, multiple sets of inputs, use **fscanf()** and use the complete code logic repeatedly for each line of input.
Hope it helps! Do ask if you need the complete code or any clarification for the code.